# Pass a reference of the button I'm clicking into the func it triggers. JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass a reference of the button I am clicking into the function it triggers?

```
jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
    .click(function() {
        myFunc(this??);
        return false;
    })


var myFunc = function (this??) {

    //I WANT TO CHECK IF THE BUTTONS PARENT HAS A SPECIFIC CLASS HERE

    if(jQuery(this??).parent().hasClass('myClass')){

        //DO STUFF HERE
    }

}
```

I can't use the class name as there are several of these buttons on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `myFunc(this)`. Its correct way to passs the element to your function
2. Use any other name other than `this` for your function parameter.

   ```
   jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
       .click(function () {
       myFunc(this);
       return false;
   });
   var myFunc = function (elem) {

       //I WANT TO CHECK IF THE BUTTONS PARENT HAS A SPECIFIC CLASS HERE

       if (jQuery(elem).parent().hasClass('myClass')) {

           //DO STUFF HERE
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass it in a separate function

```
   jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
        .click(function() {
               if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('myClass')){

                //DO STUFF HERE
            }
            return false;
        })
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a reason he wants to pass it as a argument. This doesn't necessarily answer the question correctly.

Comment: It's the same object, whether he passes it in as an argument or uses the this keyword, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `?`

```
jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
    .click(function() {
        myFunc(this);
        return false;
    })


var myFunc = function (obj) {

    //I WANT TO CHECK IF THE BUTTONS PARENT HAS A SPECIFIC CLASS HERE

    if(jQuery(obj).parent().hasClass('myClass')){

        //DO STUFF HERE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) and cannot be used as a variable (which is what you're attempting to do within your `myFunc` function. Change the name of your variable in your `myFunc` declaration:

```
var myFunc = function (myElement) { ... }
```

Then change your `if` statement to reflect that change:

```
jQuery(myElement).parent().hasClass('myClass')
```

Comment: @Grüse jQuery doesn't provide scope across a different function call, as far as I'm aware. `myFunc` is a standalone function, not related to the button element.

Comment: As far as I know it does, will try it right away :)

Comment: Ah ok, I missed the additional anonymous function in the click() call. I was referring to this case: http://jsfiddle.net/gruese/febH5/
You could also do bind() of course ...

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much knowledge about jquery but a possible solution using Js is

```
<script>
    function onClick1(b)
{

alert(b.parentNode.className);

}
</script>
<div class="divClass">
<button onclick="onClick1(this)">
    hello
</button>
</div>
```

we can pass "this" in the onclick event attribute, which passes the reference object of the element generating the event (in this case button). We then can reference the parentNode of button and its class with className property.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="myClass"> 
      <button id="btn" class="btnClass">Hi</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.btnClass').click(function() {
        myFunc(this);
    });


var myFunc = function (a) {

    //I WANT TO CHECK IF THE BUTTONS PARENT HAS A SPECIFIC CLASS HERE

    if(jQuery(a).parent().hasClass('myClass')){
        alert();
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }

}
```

[Check This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1550/)